# One wifi Multiple Passwords

Tags: networking, desktop-computer

I want to start a WiFi service in my village so that I can provide WiFi to every one but there is one problem. I want to give each and every user a different password so that they can never use another network, in short term ***one network but different password for every one*** need help.

Comment: [captive portal](https://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=captive%20portal)

Comment: "*so that they can never use another network* -- What does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

There are three options for this:

- WPA-Enterprise, as used by Eduroam and internally by corporate networks. Everyone has a separate login & password. Consider using this for security, although it can be somewhat difficult to configure.
- Authentication at a higher layer – website-based logins (captive portal). While very popular for paid hotspots due to its flexibility, this option is also quite insecure as anyone can spoof another user's MAC address.
- Some access point models support assigning different PSKs based on the device's MAC address. This is nonstandard and can get tedious to manage.

Comment: I would do this using RADIUS and WPA-Enterprise.